# How to create a child actor in akka.net using F#?

Tags: f#, akka, akka.net, actor-model

I have two actors - childActor and parentActor

```
open System
open Akka
open Akka.FSharp

let systemActor = System.create "systemActor" <| Configuration.defaultConfig()

let childActor (mailbox: Actor<_>) = 
    let rec loop() = actor {
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        printfn "Message received"
        return! loop()
    }
    loop()

let parentActor (mailbox: Actor<_>) = 
    let rec loop() = actor {
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        printfn "Message received"
        return! loop()
    }
    loop()
```

I can create the parent actor reference using spawn function.

```
let parentRef = spawn systemActor "parentActor" parentActor
```

Now what I want to do here is to create the child actor reference under parent actor. Something like below.

```
let childRef = spawn parentRef "childActor" childActor
```

But this is not working. spawn function requires a parameter of type IActorRefFactory so it is not accepting IActorRef. Is there any way to create a child actor under parent actor in akka.net using F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IActorRefFactory` is an interface responsible for determining a parent and in case of Akka.FSharp it's implemented by `ActorSystem` and `Actor<_>` as well. So in your case just use:

```ml
let childRef = spawn mailbox "childActor" childActor
```

Comment: Just to be clear, that line of code has to be added to the `parentActor` function, right? Otherwise, it's not clear how the parent/child relationship is created.

Comment: Yes, since first `spawn` parameter specifies the parent. If you'll pass `mailbox` of the current actor, that actor will be treated as parent. 

If you pass `ActorSystem` it means, that this system's `/user` actor will become the parent - `/user` is a special root actor created implicitly when actor system starts.